# How can i remove same item in list

Tags: c#

Could you help me? I cant remove the same item in a list.

```cs
List<string> text = new List<string>();
text.Add("A");
text.Add("B");
text.Add("C");
text.Add("D");
text.Add("D");
text.Add("A");
foreach(string i in text)
{
 Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

the result is A,B,C,D,D,A  but I need to be B,C . How can i do?

Comment: He wants to remove all occurences of the elements that occur more than once, right?

Comment: I need to remove  the same item out of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
text.GroupBy(t => t).Where(tg => tg.Count()==1).Select(td => td.First());
```

This proberly wont compile, you need to fix that your self.

The idea is:
1. Group by item.
2. Take all groups with exactly 1 item
3. Select the Item

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution,

```
 var result = text.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() == 1).Select(z => z.Key); 
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

---

Explanation:

[GroupBy(x => x):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) This will group list based on characters i.e predicate.

[.Where(y => y.Count() == 1):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) This will filter elements which are duplicates.

[.Select(z => z.Key):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) Select will create new enumerable which contains `Keys` from Grouped elements